# Files deleted from SD card are restored after restart

Tags: external-sd, file-management

I use my sd to watch movies, everything was working fine, suddenly every time I reboot my tab the deleted files are back in the sd card.

I tried to format and still same issue, the deleted files are always coming back.

I tried many apps, they seems to delete the files, but if I reboot or format the sd they come back.

Comment: Some apps are probably restoring them back.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the cache on your  File Manager,  the browser you used to download the movies, and for the application  involved used to play the movies.

For each of those applications select the application and clear its cache:

Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > All (at the top) > {application} > Clear Cache

Answer (score 1):

Your SD card most likely got broken: I've had the exact same issue a while back on another device. I'd recommend using a card reader to attach the card to your computer, and do a check for [bad blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector). In my case it turned out almost all sectors were "bad" – with the effect that the old data remained, and all "writes" went to Nirvana:

- delete file: reappeared after boot
- add file: disappeared after boot

Reason is, those changes are just kept in your device's cache, so it appeared they were performed correctly. On boot, that cache was purged.

So your solution would be: Get yourself a new SD card. Optionally copy over the files which you want to keep from your old one. Now everything should work fine again.